# How to create a form to change part of a href url of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I want to have a form (like a textarea with a submit button or something simple) that can change part of the link of another button (shown below).

This form would only change the 'receiveAddr' part of the href link (would change "1313mainstreetlosangeles" to the address the user submits) but keep everything else the same.

So changing only part of an href link in a button based on the text a user submits.

Is there any way to do this?

```
<a class="button" id="btn" href="https://url.com/v1/?type=buy&amp;mode=popup&amp;receiveAddr=1313mainstreetlosangelesca&amp;receiveType=USD&amp;callback=url.com" target="_blank">Buy now</a>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible with JS and JQuery with a `replace()` or something like that, but please show a more completely code to understand the purpose of the forms and which one has to change what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sensible solution:

```js
var changeForm = document.forms['changeBtn'],
    regex = /receiveAddr=(.*?)&/;

changeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit function
    
    var form = e.target,
     btn = document.getElementById('btn'),
     href = btn.href,
        textareaVal = encodeURIComponent(form.receiveAddr.value.trim());
      
    btn.href = href.replace(regex, 'receiveAddr=' + textareaVal + '&');
});
```

```html
<form id="changeBtn">
    <textarea name="receiveAddr"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>


<a class="button" id="btn" href="https://url.com/v1/?type=buy&amp;mode=popup&amp;receiveAddr=1313mainstreetlosangelesca&amp;receiveType=USD&amp;callback=url.com" target="_blank">Buy now</a>
```

Solution Overkill:

```js
var changeForm = document.forms['changeBtn'],
    regexFirstPart = /(.*)\?/;

changeForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit function
    
    var form = e.target,
     href = document.getElementById('btn').href,
     firstPart = regexFirstPart.exec(href)[0],
        urlParts = processQuery(href); // ends with ?
      
    urlParts.receiveAddr = changeForm.receiveAddr.value;
    
    btn.href = firstPart + objectToUrlParams(urlParts);
});

function processQuery(url) {
    var regex = /[?&]([^=#]+)=([^&#]*)/g,
        params = {},
        match;
    while (match = regex.exec(url)) {
        params[match[1]] = match[2];
    }
    return params;
}

function objectToUrlParams(obj) {
    var str = "";
    for (var key in obj) {
        if (str != "") {
            str += "&";
        }
        str += key + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]);
    }
    return str;
}
```

```html
<form id="changeBtn">
    <textarea name="receiveAddr"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>


<a class="button" id="btn" href="https://url.com/v1/?type=buy&amp;mode=popup&amp;receiveAddr=1313mainstreetlosangelesca&amp;receiveType=USD&amp;callback=url.com" target="_blank">Buy now</a>
```

Comment: @mplungjan xD If slightly traumatized, I can point you to a therapy site. It's called Code Golf... :) Thoughts on recent answer?

Comment: Better :) So much better. A little dangerous if there are special chars in the address and you really should trim and encodeURIComponent

Comment: See my second solution which does not care about special chars and does not need a regex

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

You will need a [polyfill for IE](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params)

```js
let url = new URL("https://url.com/v1/?type=buy&mode=popup&receiveAddr=1313mainstreetlosangelesca&receiveType=USD&callback=url.com");
let params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var addr = document.getElementById("addr").value.trim();
  if (addr) {
    params.set('receiveAddr', addr);
    url.search = params.toString();
    this.href=url;
    console.log(url);
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("addr").focus();
    alert("Please fill in an address");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addr" />
<a class="button" id="btn" target="_blank">Buy now</a>
```

Alternative - NOTE the encodeURIComponent

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  var addr = document.getElementById("addr").value.trim();
  if (addr) {
    addr = encodeURIComponent(addr);
    var url = `https://url.com/v1/?type=buy&mode=popup&receiveAddr=${addr}&receiveType=USD&callback=url.com`
    this.href=url;
    console.log(url);
  } else {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("addr").focus();
    alert("Please fill in an address");
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="addr" />
<a class="button" id="btn" target="_blank">Buy now</a>
```

Comment: Note: URLSearchParams has [no IE support](https://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams), but that could be solved with a polyfill. Regardless, great solution :)

Comment: I feel like that's cheating... :( xD

Answer (score 0):

Tricky solution:

```
textarea=//your textarea
var value="";
if(textarea.value==null){
value="1313mainstreetlosangelesca";
}else{
value=textarea.value;
}
```

Then add link to document:

```
link='<a class="button" id="btn" href="https://url.com/v1/?type=buy&amp;mode=popup&amp;receiveAddr='+value+'&amp;receiveType=USD&amp;callback=url.com" target="_blank">Buy now</a>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Use String interpolation of a variable that would be set with the new address upon submission of the form

Comment: OP likely does not know what _String interpolation_ means. please give an example when you answer a question like this. It is no longer necessary since the other answers have plenty examples